# Video capture with comments on Google Glass: Which card type should I use?

Tags: google-glass, google-gdk

I'm trying to build my first "Glassware", using the GDK.
I want to record a video and let the user add written comments to the video, which means that I can't use the Intent way for video capture, and I'll have to implement a surfaceHolder.
**My question is - which card (or activity) should I use for this?**
I'm not sure if I need to use immersions or LiveCard is enough.
And which LiveCard? [the low or high frequency?](https://developers.google.com/glass/develop/gdk/ui/live-cards) I couldn't figure it out from the GDK sneak-peek.
Thanks

Comment: Sounds like an Immersion rather than a LiveCard, since you want full control over the rendering. I'm not an expert by any means, but from what I've read this would seem to be one of those situations.

Comment: How were you going to add "written comments" to the video?

Comment: @ErstwhileIII, It will be added as "semi-automatic" messages in which the user will be able to change certain parameters. on tap, the user will be able to choose from a list of messages, and in each message he will enter the relevant info. probably with voice-recognition.
I started building it with Immersion, I figured that the best solution for this kind of app..

Comment: I think you don't need to do a "immersion", you should be able to directly capture the video or picture, have the user add the categories/comments and then send the video yourself.  I will look into this and try to provide an answer late tonight.